# Efficiency of Browserify with multiple bundles

Tags: javascript, browserify, dynamic-script-loading

I'm new to Browserify and I'm trying to figure out how to make it more efficient with regards to how much the client needs to download.

I have a web app, that uses many different 3rd party libraries and custom code. With Browserify, it seems like the general approach people suggest is to wrap everything up into one big `bundle.js`. This seems horribly inefficient to me for several reasons:

For example, lets say your `bundle.js` contains `lib1, lib2, lib3, customLib`.

1. If a part of your web app only needs `lib1` the client still has to download a huge `bundle.js` and it ends up not using 75% of it. Wasted bytes downloaded. Unnecessarily increased page load time.
2. If your `customLib` is a piece of code that you iterate upon often, then every time it changes, your clients have to redownload `bundle.js`, again downloading a ton of 3rd party libraries that haven't changed...

Other parts of your web app may use `lib2` and `lib3` but the client may or may not ever go to there, in which he definitely wasted bandwidth downloading the entire `bundle.js`.

I've seen suggestions to split up your bundle into multiple bundles. But to what end? If one page uses `lib1`, another page uses `lib1` and `lib2` and another page uses `lib2` and `lib3`, then how do you split it up? The more you split it up into multiple bundles aren't you getting away from the advantages of `bundle.js`?

Browserify seems to be highly regarded so I hope that I am just missing something here. What is the proper approach to bundling together many libraries and custom scripts together? People call Browserify a "script loader" but every script loader I've seen in the past (like `yepnope` etc), use logic to determine which scripts to download, which seems like a much more efficient solution, while Browserify appears to want the client to download everything...

Comment: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#partitioning

Comment: Hmmm that is what I was looking for I think. Does that allow you to keep all libraries in individual (or optionally combining certain ones) files and still load them dynamically?

Comment: I think so. Check this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/partition-bundle
I haven't used it yet (but I'm planning too).

Comment: Yeah that looks really good actually. Feel free to submit your answer as an actual answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if the answer fits SO format well. But nevertheless...

[Partitioning Section](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#partitioning) of handbook describes 2 following techniques

1. [factor-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/factor-bundle) factors 2 or more entry points placing common dependencies into a single bundle.
2. [partition-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/partition-bundle) same as factor-bundle but with runtime loading using async `loadjs` function.

Factor bundle

```
<script src="/bundle/common.js"></script>
<script src="/bundle/x.js"></script>
```

Partition bundle with async loading fallback

```
loadjs(['./x'], function(x){...});
```

Comment: Do you have to use a closure to load the module? Can you not use it outside the closure?

Comment: I doubt that. You have to somehow make sure the module was loaded. `loadjs` makes request on the first call and caches the result. So there is no overhead on subsequent calls. Kinda AMDish way of doing things.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko. I am trying loading files with partition bundle. Here's my situation:
Module 'a' is in /js/bundle-user.js and this js file is in public folder accessible at /js/
The page is hosted at http://localhost:8888/settings.
I am trying loadjs('./a') in this file but it tries to load bundle-user.js from http://localhost:8888/bundle-user.js instead from http://localhost:8888/js/bundle-user.js
Any idea how to solve this.?

Answer (score 1):

Substack just [published this gist](https://gist.github.com/substack/68f8d502be42d5cd4942) explaining how to split bundles. He suggests to use [factor-bundle](https://npmjs.org/package/factor-bundle) like this:

```
browserify x.js y.js -p [ factor-bundle -o bundle/x.js -o y.js ] \
  -o bundle/common.js
```